# Well Known Binary GeometryCollection for GeoPackage doesn't show in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I wanted to test QGIS/GeoPackage with the Well Known Binary for: WKBGeometryCollection(WKBMultipoint(WKBPoint, WKBpoint))

I was guided by the document "OGC 06-103r4" for Geopackage and generated the following BLOB:

```
4750000000000f11000000000700000001000000000400000002000000000141515cbb6b198b4c4156a84c9a39b482000000000141515cd46b198b4c4156a8659a39b482
```

This doesn't show in QGIS. When I leave out WKBGeometryCollection, it works perfect:

```
4750000000000f11000000000400000002000000000141515cbb6b198b4c4156a84c9a39b482000000000141515cd46b198b4c4156a8659a39b482
```

Comment: What is your question? Right now this seems to be a bug report (though "doesn't work" isn't the most useful of problem descriptions), which are off-topic here.

Comment: It isn't a bug report. I just want to know how to properly use WKBGeometryCollection in GeoPackage. With the first BLOB from above QGis doesn't show the expected two points.